# Should off-topic answers be flagged as “Requires Moderator attention”?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators

I've come across situations where the question asked is "How do you do X in Java?" and one of the answers is "Can someone help me do Y?"

Should I flag that response as “Requires Moderator attention”?  Or should I just downvote it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention. Go nuts with the thing.

You have 10 flags for moderator attention a day, use them. There can never be enough flags for moderator attention.

Write out why you think it should be cast into the hoary fires of Hoggarth and a mod will come along and blast that salt walker into the back of the supermarket.

Downvote and flag as spam/offensive in addition if you feel it's right.

Comment: coffee just came out of my nose.

Comment: For once I agree with random! If you see something that you don't like and you can't do anything to fix it yourself (no edit privileges, no close privileges, an off topic answer, an old duplicate question that since it's not at the top of the active list no other 4 people will vote to close, etc), then flag it for a mod. They'll hopefully be happy to help clean up the site! After all, that's why they volunteered.

Comment: I completely agree with that. Flag all you want, there can never be too much of it. Flags are the most direct way for moderators to find problems. We get notified about them, and deal with them easily. Don't be afraid to use them, especially if you see something which went unnoticed by the community, like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

I generally post a comment to the response, politely explaining why the post is inappropriate, and asking the poster to delete it.  If it is spam or abusive, you can flag it as such, and the system will delete it automatically when six such flags are accumulated.

If all that fails, it is entirely appropriate to flag for moderator attention.